# How to remove "Debug Current Instruction Pointer"

Tags: eclipse

I tried to use the debugger in Eclipse, but when I hit my 
breakpoints, the Eclipse "Debug Current Instruction Pointer" is often 
pointing at the wrong source line.I really want to remove "Debug Current Instruction Pointer". "Project -> Clean..." doesn't seem to help, nor does 
restarting Eclipse, nor does rebooting.

Answer (score 6):

The "Debug Current Instruction Pointer" is the position where you paused debugging last time. You can simply resolve it by following the below two steps

1. Go to the "Debug" preference/panel
2. Then click on the red square button to terminate the debugging you were executing last time or press **Ctrl+F2** (Windows)
   [image]

Now, just **debug** the program again. The execution will be starting from the "Toggle Breakpoint".

**Note:** You can delete the Toggle Breakpoint by double click on the line number and redefine the new according to your requirements by right click on targeted line number and select "Toggle BreakPoint" or press **Ctrl+Shift+B** (Windows)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the debug view (as your current debug session is running) and complete or terminate current debugging session. this way you will get rid of "Debug Current Instruction Pointer"

Comment: Nop, the line still remains. I need to close Eclipse (Oxygen)... very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was remove all breakpoints - right-click, RemoveAll.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes breakpoints remain in eclipse list even after we remove them by clicking over them, to remove

1. Show Breakpoints view by navigating menu

> Window>>Show View>>Other>>    Select Debug>>Breakpoints

2. In Breakpoints view, uncheck unnecessary breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this pointer from ever being displayed in the first place, go to

> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations ->
>   select Debug Current Instruction Pointer -> uncheck "Vertical ruler"
>   box

Answer (score 0):

"Debug Current Insturction Pointer" isn't something you would want to remove since it is not something that is set in any way, ist just a pointer to the current instruction where the debugger has paused your application. You can see that easily if you just step through your application and see how the "Debug Current Insturction Pointer" is moving along.

If you think it is pointing at the wrong source-line there are two reasons I can think of right now:

1. There are some "old" breakpoints left from earlier debug-sessions. You should see the breakpoint-marker and be able to remove it. If you want to get rid of all existing breakpoints just go to the breakpoints-view and remove them all using the double-X-icon.
2. The source-file shown in the debug-window doesn't match the class file that is currently running. This is most likely to happen in some imported libraries and not in your own project's code, but if it still does happen a clean/rebuild should take care of the problem.

Comment: Neither suggestion helps. Feels more like an eclipse bug than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get out of the current debug session. Go to the debug console and end the current session by hitting the red square button.
This should remove all the debug **current instruction pointers.**

Answer (score 0):

Check the arguments written in Run Configuration, because they can be wrong.
To reach Run Configuration, right click the project's main class  -> Run As -> Run Configurations -> Java Application on menu -> Arguments. In the text Area write your arguments and try to debug again.